# Liquid filter for not included in array?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to list all pages that does not have the tag 'app'

This works for items with the tag app:

```
{% assign pages = site.pages | where:"tags",page.list_tag | where_exp:"page", "page.tags contains 'app'" | sort:"order_number" %}
```

but I can't use "unless":

```
{% assign pages = site.pages | where:"tags",page.list_tag | where_exp:"page", "unless page.tags contains 'app'" | sort:"order_number" %}
```

I get this error:

```
Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 2): Expected end_of_string but found id in /_layouts/list.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible yet. In this case, I think you'll have to loop through the pages and include an `unless` condition inside your loop. So something like:

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
    {% unless page.tags contains 'app' %}
        {{ page.title }}
    {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```